# Yet another case of serial minor tag editing

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits

[Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195422/even-more-serial-minor-edits)

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1053103/mike-causer?tab=activity) has been suggesting tag-only edits that, for the most part, just add [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) to [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) questions, without improving anything else. He's at **60 approved (!) and 12 rejected (`:(`).** (update 14:04 UTC time: 96/46) The queue has reached over 80 edits at one point!

This is partially a call to action, since I, one of the main rejectors, just ran out of suggested edit reviews.

However, [since](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210391) [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164503/) [has](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168190/)
[come](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168191/) [up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116509/)
[a](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128514/) [lot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195422), I really, *really* think we need to do something about this.

So what do I suggest that's not already been suggested? I say that there should be a smaller edit ban, that lasts a shorter amount of time, for, say, 3 or 4 suggestions rejected in a day (except the ones rejected by Community). This could be a 1 or 2-day ban.

Also, I think that there should be a maximum of 1 suggestion every 2 minutes (or something like that), which this user is blowing far past, indicating no real thought to the edits.

I also promote these other requests:

- [No rep for tag-only edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197069/180276)
- [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120624/180276)
- [Pending approvals: allow for adding reasons to rejections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77875/180276)
- [Do we need a Bat-Signal on Meta, calling in help when the edit queue is full?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129850/180276)

Comment: Wow, that guy needs to be stopped *now*. Up to 17 rejects now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yep, typed up this question as fast as I could :P

Comment: +1. Nice proposal but I think some things need to be considered. I once had 5 suggested edits rejected because a 2k rep user edited the post at the time I did so Community Rejected it. Should that have given me a ban for 3 days?

Comment: @Tijesunimi GOod point, but IIRC Community-rejected edits don't count toward the normal ban anyway. I'll edit my question

Comment: This guy needs a *rate limit*!

Comment: Out of reviews. 20 rejects **all for this guy**.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The worst part is his edits are getting approved. I just tried rejecting some of his edits but I got `This edit has already been approved please go to the post and correct it`.

Comment: At this point, they has suggested 125 edits in 2 hours.  They must be really bored. _oops, 129 edits...sorry, 131 edits_ It just keeps climbing.  I did attempt to comment to them [suggesting they fix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026053/sql-and-php-database-access#comment30507447_4026053) everything in a post.  Doesn't look like they got the message.

Comment: @bluefeet I don't think you can just ping random users; it has to be on a post where they contributed (the user didn't edit that post as seen in the revision history)

Comment: Could minitech ♦ start applying edit-suggest bans as well as review bans?

Comment: @Doorknob While I can't fix my comment from above, I added another comment to one of their answers asking them to fix everything in the posts that they edit.  Maybe now they will get the message. :)  [He even responded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262844/how-do-i-get-the-filename-of-the-executing-jade-script/20352336#comment30508800_20352336)

Comment: The edits seem to have stopped coming. What happened? (Autoban?)

Comment: @michaelb958 Maybe. The call to action worked! Yay!

Comment: 60 approved sounds horrible, we really need [some "too minor" audits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183977/add-too-minor-audits-to-review-queue).